# Is it possible to include a single frame (Frameset) in a HTML5 document?

Tags: html, frames

I've been asked by a client to create a standard HTML5 template but include a frame (Frameset not iframe) to use as the footer.

I've only worked with frames a handful of times so I don't really know if it's possible or not.

Here's a very simple example of what I need

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<meta name="description" content="" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>

<body>

<div id="content">
    <!-- ALL CONTENT GOES HERE -->
</div>

<!-- FOOTER FRAME WOULD GO HERE -->

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't think framesets are supported in HTML5 anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [HTML5 differences from HTML4](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5-diff/):

> The following elements are not in HTML5 because using them damages usability and accessibility:
>
> ```
> frame
> frameset
> noframes
> ```

what your client wants to do can be done within the page without using frames, even though it's not completely easy. One approach would be to have a content area that has `overflow: auto`(causing it to be scrolled) and stretches almost to the bottom of the page.

Another approach is to have a footer div that is `position: fixed`.

Comment: Believe me I've tried a dozen times to get them to use another method but they're set on using frames

Comment: @Dean then they can't use HTML 5.

Answer (score 0):

Theres a Semantic Tag named `<footer>...</footer>` you should use for Footer, with Fixed Position and ID